# What is the correct syntax for calling this C function in C#? The function uses pointers and arrays

Tags: c#, python, c, pointers, dllimport

I'm trying to call a function from a DLL written in C. I need to call the function in C#, but I believe I'm running into issues with the syntax. I have a working example that uses the [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) library in Python. Unfortunately the DLL requires a dongle to run, so right now I'm looking for help regarding any obvious discrepancies in the syntax between C, Python, and C#.

The C function has the format

`int (int nID, int nOrientation, double *pMTFVector, int *pnVectorSize );` 
(I'm really unfamiliar with pointers and the PDF documentation has the asterisks surrounded by spaces so I'm not sure what the asterisk should be attached to)

The function of this code is to accept nID and nOrientation to specify features in an image, and then populate an array with values. The documentation describes the outputs below:

```
out; pMTFVector; array of MTF values, memory is allocated and handled by application, size is given by pnVectorSize

in,out; pnVectorSize maximum number of results allowed to store in pMTFVector, number of results found and stored in pMTFVector
```

The python code that actually works is:

```
lib=cdll.LoadLibrary("MTFCameraTester.dll")
lib.MTFCTGetMTF(c_uint(0), c_int(0), byref((c_double * 1024)()), byref(c_uint(1024)))
```

The code I've tried is:

```
 [DllImport("MTFCameraTester.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public extern static MTFCT_RETURN MTFCTGetMTF(UInt32 nID, int orientation, double[] theArray, IntPtr vectorSize);

        double[] myArray = new double[1024];
        IntPtr myPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(1024);
        returnEnum = MTFCTGetMTF(0, 0, myArray, myPtr);
```

When the code is run my `returnEnum` is `-1`, which is specified as an error in the documentation. This is the best result I've come across, as I've had many Stack Overflow errors when trying varying combinations of `ref` and `out`

Comment: An array is already marshalled as a pointer to the first element. So I think that `ByRef theArray() As Double` should be `theArray() As Double`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'll edit the bottom of my original question, as I'm not sure how to cleanly format comments.

Comment: I've shifted my question to C# as that seems to be the most common language I ran across while searching for help. I've also added more information from the documentation about the inputs/outputs and the purpose of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly there. The final argument is the problem I think. Try like this:

```
[DllImport("MTFCameraTester.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public extern static MTFCT_RETURN MTFCTGetMTF(
    uint nID,
    int orientation,
    [Out] double[] theArray, 
    ref int vectorSize
);

....

double[] myArray = new double[1024];
int vectorSize = myArray.Length;
MTFCT_RETURN returnEnum = MTFCTGetMTF(0, 0, myArray, ref vectorSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

The VB.NET solution that worked was:

```
   <DllImport("MTFCameraTester.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)> _
    Function MTFCTGetMTF(ByVal id As UInt32, ByVal orientation As UInt32, ByRef data As Double, ByRef len As UInt32) As Integer
    End Function

    Dim ret As Integer
    Dim dat(1023) As Double
    Dim len As UInt32 = 1024
    ret = MTFCTGetMTF(0, 0, dat(0), len)
```

It seems like I had to pass the first element of the array to the C function, and then it took care of the rest.

Comment: This isn't right at all. You need to declare the array as an array.

Comment: I didn't believe the syntax either, but it populates my dat array correctly. I'm not sure if the documentation had an error, but this exact code works for the function I'm calling. I accepted your answer because your syntax makes sense and should have worked, but the code itself returned an error.